# How do I control speed using servo.h?

Tags: arduino, servo

I have an Arduino mega 2560 attached to a 4 wheeled robot (similar to this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPqZQsKHJ9s&feature=related) .

Pin 9 on the Arduino is connected to the front wheels of the robot to move either left or right.

Pin 10 on the Arduino is connected to the back wheels for forward movement.

I have successfully sent "LEFT" and "RIGHT" signals to the arduino and have gotten the robot to turn left and right respectively.

However, I am struggling to have control on the pin 10 which controls forward/backward movement. When I send any signal to over pin 10 the robot moves the wheels in forward direction at maximum speed.  I cannot let the robot sit on a table for testing because it goes out of control.  I have to physically lift it from the table so the wheels do not touch the ground when testing pin 10.

Here is the code that works correctly for left and right signals:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello Pi");
  Serial.println("attaching to pin 9");
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
}

void loop()
{ 
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    char command = Serial.read();
    if (command=='L'){

      turn_left();
      delay(5000);
    }
    else if (command=='R'){
      turn_right();
      delay(5000);
    }

  }
}

void turn_left(){
  myservo.write(500);
}

void turn_right(){
  myservo.write(0);    
}
```

And here is the code for moving forward that does not work

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello Pi");
  Serial.println("attaching to pin 10");
  myservo.writeMicroseconds(544); // im confused what this does..
  myservo.attach(10);  // attaches the servo on pin 10 to the servo object
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    char command = Serial.read();
    if (command=='L'){

      move_forward(); // right now does the same thing is move_backward()
      delay(5000);
    }
    else if (command=='R'){

      move_backward(); // right now does the same thing as move_forward()
      delay(5000);
    }

  }

}

void turn_left(){
  myservo.write(500);
}

void turn_right(){
  myservo.write(0);    
}
// as soon as either of the two functions below is invoked 
// the robot goes at MAXIMUM speed forward.  I have no clue how to slow it down.
void move_forward(){
  myservo.write(0);
}

void move_backward(){
  myservo.write(0);
}
```

Comment: Is your front/back movement really a continuous rotation servo? I would have thought it was more likely to be a standard DC motor.

Comment: @PeterJ A continuous rotation servo simplifies speed control as well as eliminates the need to add a H-bridge and its requisite control GPIOs for direction control (there's an H-bridge inside the servo). Hence it's a popular hobbyist choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really just guessing here, but according to [the documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoWrite),

> "write() ... Writes a value to the servo... On a continuous rotation
>   servo, this will set the speed of the servo (with 0 being full-speed
>   in one direction, 180 being full speed in the other, and a value near
>   90 being no movement)."

Have you tried maybe doing a `myservo.write(90);` which according to that documentation should be slow or stopped?

Comment: hmm, you might be on to something.  Let me get back to you about this.  I only have access to the vehicle when I'm in the lab.  As soon as I try your recommendation I'll post another note here.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just type this code instead of yours which is:

```
void move_forward(){
myservo.write(90,30);//to ensure a minimum speed because 0=full speed and 1-255 from slow to high speed
}

void move_backward(){
myservo.write(90,30);//like the previous
}
```

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE Omar. You can format code by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` in the editor.

Comment: @uint128_t Thx for you guidance

Comment: Servo.write only accepts one parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You'll find the answer here : https://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/ese205/core/index.php?title=Servo_Motor_(Continuous_Rotation)_%2B_Arduino. "One of the most important functions is the servo.write(speed). It sets the speed of the servo with 0 being full-speed in one direction, 180 being full speed in the other direction and 90 being no movement."

Comment: This is the same as an earlier answer, and adds nothing new.